# Firebase Storage Trigger Not Working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I created a custom bucket which I use to serve content at a specific url. In Firebase I created a bucket called "images.mydomain.com" and I wanted to use this so my users can simply go to http://images.mydomain.com/imagename.jpg to access uploaded images.

I wanted to have a firebase trigger on my new bucket that does Google vision analysis on the image. Here is my function:

```
export const imageUploaded = functions.storage
.bucket('images.mydomain.com').object().onChange( event => {
    //Cool stuff happens here
});
```

However, when I try to deploy the function I get this error in the console

> ⚠  functions[imageUploaded]: Deployment error.
>
> Failed to configure trigger GCS Bucket: imagebucket

When I go to the function logs in Firebase I see the exact same error

> Failed to configure trigger GCS Bucket: imagebucket

I also went to the Google Cloud Console to look at the functions to hopefully get some more insight on the issue. When I looked at the function, it had the correct bucket configured for the function but it had that exact same error without any explanation.

I have tried to create a new bucket using that but I get the exact same error. It seems that no matter what I do I keep getting the same error. I've tried adding permission and every It doesn't make any sense.

Does anyone know what this is about and/or how I can get this working? I had this working on the main bucket, but I really need this to work for my new bucket.

Thanks

A quick update:

I tried to deploy to my production environment (my app isn't in market yet so no one is actually using it) and it worked perfectly, the trouble is, I really need my development environment working which isn't right now.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for help.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue I used this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/66

Basically, there was no answer, I just had to shutdown my development project and start a new development project. Once I started a new project my functions deployed perfectly.